# how to check con 1 and (con 2 or con 3)

Tags: python, list

so my code is

```
wh = []
wh.append("2")
wh.append("lodw")
if wh[0] == "1" and wh[1] == "lol" or wh[1] == "lodw":
 print("da")
else:
 print("net")
```

the problem is it gives me true even if wh at 0 isnt "1"

Comment: You've answered your own question in the title - put parentheses around the `or` part.

Comment: You missed to add `parantheses`().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you check the value of wh[1] is a specific string you can do

```
if wh[0] == "1" and wh[1] in ("lol", "lodw"):
```

Or to use any with all

```
if all((wh[0] == "1", any((wh[1] == "lol", wh[1] == "lodw")))):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` clause is equal to :

```
if (wh[0] == "1" and wh[1] == "lol" )or wh[1] == "lodw":
```

Therefore, the statement is `true`
Set paranthisis if you want to achieve `False`:

```
if wh[0] == "1" and (wh[1] == "lol" or wh[1] == "lodw"):
```